# How to pass down data through 3 class components in react correctly?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

This is a react beginners exercise, so please be patient and don't overwhelm with the latest best practice.

For this exercise I need 3 class components:

1. **Main.js:** which basically just holds an array
2. **List.js:** which maps through that array and with each iteration passes the element of the array to Item.js
3. **Item.js:** here you render the mapped array

I am quite confident with the first two components but unable to make the jump from  2 to 3. **Who can not only post the answer but also comment out the key ideas? Thx!**

What I have so far for Main.js and List.js

**Main.js**

```
import React from "react";

export const avengers = ["Ironman", "Thor", "Hulk", "Hawkeye", "Black Widow"]
```

**List.js**

```
import React from "react";
import Main, { avengers } from "Main.js";


class List extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {avengers.map((superhero, index) =>
                    <Item key={index} superhero={superhero}/>
                )}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default List;
```

**Item.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import List from "./List.js";

class Item extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
          <div>
            {this.props.superhero}
          </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Item;
```

Comment: The key idea should be `key={index}` ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One problem you have is when passing props

```
<Item key="index" superhero="{superhero}" />
```

You should be passing it like

```
<Item key={index} superhero={superhero} />
```

If you put is ass `someProp="something"` you are just passing a string.

If you want to pass a variable, you need to pass it like `someProp={someVariable}`

And the prop can be access inside `Item` like `this.props.someProp` (if it's a class component, or `props.someProp` if is a functional component, where `props` is the parameter of your functional component.

## Edit

One mistake I just saw in your code is these two lines

```
const avengers = ["Ironman", "Thor", "Hulk", "Hawkeye", "Black Widow"]
```

and

```
import avengers from "Main.js";
```

In the first line, you create `avangers` but you never `export` it, so you want be able to `import` it.

What you need to do is add `export` and when importing, import it by the name (inside `{}`) because the way you are importing, you are getting the `default` export.

So here is how it should be

```
// added export
export const avengers = ["Ironman", "Thor", "Hulk", "Hawkeye", "Black Widow"]
```

and

```
// importing avengers correctly
import Main, { avengers } from "Main.js";
```

## Edit 2

Not sure if this is what you want, but I will guess

```
class Item extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
          <div>
            {this.props.superhero}
          </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Item;
```

## Last Edit

I made you a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/avengers-list-b0mk3) with a working example. Please take a look and see how it works, play around with it and try to learn from it. Hope this helps ;)

Comment: thx ... updated. The reason is, that I enter javascript in JSX with the curly brackets, right?

Comment: @Stephan-thecurious sorry I couldn't understand you correctly, The reason of what?

Comment: the reason that I use curly braces instead of quotation marks.

Comment: How would Item.js look like as a class component passing through the props?

Comment: @Stephan-thecurious Please share your `Item` component. If it's already an functional component,it's much better. Also, check my edit, I found some mistakes

Comment: I updated for Item.js and also for the code you suggested so far. I didn't post it because I felt it must be very wrong. Anyhow, I saw your update.

Comment: @Stephan-thecurious Why `Item` have `List` inside and `List` have `Item` inside?

Comment: Honestly .... I don't know. I try to accomplish this part of my exercise. Quoting: *"List you should map through the array and for each iteration you should pass each element of the array to Item in which you render it."*

Comment: I get an error message, that Item in List.js is not defined and I updated my code for all your suggestions so far

Comment: @Stephan-thecurious where? What file? What line? What is your file structure? Are you sure you are importing from the right file? Please be more specifc, I'm trying to help but I need more information

Comment: It refers to line 10 in the Line.js file (that I posted above) and it says **"'Item' is not defined. react/jsx-no-undef"**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199912/discussion-between-stephan-the-curious-and-vencovsky).